# How can I add a link to a NAS on my desktop in Raspbian?

Tags: linux, network-shares, raspberry-pi

I've created a mount to my NAS in Raspbian. It works, and I can access it via the File Manager.

Is it possible for me to put a link to the file manager which will open in that share's folder on the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Simply creating the folder myNas on the desktop, and then configuring /etc/fstab to mount the NAS at startup, e.g.

```
//192.168.1.15/Public /pi/Desktop/myNas cifs guest 0 0
```

means that clicking the folder on the desktop opens to the NAS share.

Comment: Nothing like answering your own question :)

Comment: Yeah, thinking about it now I get the same satisfaction out of it as I get from clicking the link on the desktop, which is a lot! :-)